# 'Exception : invalid image data ' error in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am learning flutter development with dart from udemy , and I am stuck in this part of the course , in this code it is supposed to display a centered image on the emulator app ( I already activated internet on the emulator and I can execute google research !)
that's my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';                                                    
void main                                                                                     
{                                                                                       
  runApp(
  MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('I am Rich'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Image(
        image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

);
}

Comment: Works as it is for me. What IDE / emulator do you use?

Comment: I use android studio , with emulated nexus 6p running on android 11 !

Comment: I tried with Visual Studio Code and iOS simulator, and it worked. Try `flutter clean` and build again, also try running on your phone instead of emulator.